# Observing keydown events in JavaScript when two keys are pressed simultaneously

Tags: javascript, events, keypress, key, simultaneous

I'm developing a browser game using JavaScript where the player can move an avatar in all four directions.

In order to register simultaneous key presses I observe the `keydown` and `keyup` events and keep track of the keys that are pressed and released. That way I can move the avatar in a diagonal direction if for example *cursor up* and *cursor right* are pressed at the same time.

It's the same principle from this reply here on StackOverflow [In Javascript, how do I tell if a user is pressing two keys at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018214/in-javascript-how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-pressing-two-keys-at-the-same-time/2018286#2018286) with this demonstration http://jsbin.com/iloxi.

However there's a flaw in that solution which can also be reproduced in the demo. For example press *cursor down*, then also start pressing *cursor right*. The box now moves bottom right. Now release *cursor right* while still pressing *cursor down*. The box stops moving. What should happen is that the box keeps moving down.

The problem is that JavaScript stops sending *cursor down* `keydown` events as soon as *cursor right* is pressed. Once *cursor right* is released there's no way of knowing that *cursor down* is still being pressed.

Is there a solution to this problem?

**Update:** The problem with the demo is that the box is moved either in the `keydown` or `keyup` event listeners. However once the second key is released no more `keydown` events are fired for the first key. I'm wondering if there's a solution to this or if this is standard JavaScript behavior?

To fix the demo code you would have to call the `move()` function in a timeout iteration (`window.setTimeout()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but shouldn't you just wait for a `keyup` event on cursor down?  i.e. cursor down is being pressed until you get a `keyup` for it - you shouldn't be relying on repeated `keydown` events being sent.

Comment: I think he's wanting the avatar to move while the key is being held, then stop on keyup.

Comment: ghoppe is right. I'm just wondering why the demo (see link above) doesn't work as expected. I have the same problem with my code which I wrote from scratch.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  I'm saying what you should do is just use the keydown and keyup events to keep track of what keys are pressed, and then do the actual moving in your timer loop.  (Presumably you'll have a timer loop, since this is a game and you'll have other game logic to handle.)  This will also eliminate the slightly longer delay you get between the first and second "steps".

Comment: kprevas, that's exactly what I was thinking right now :) I updated the question for clarification.